# Enable Developer options in Kindle Fire Second Generation

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire, developer-options

I have a kindle fire second generation with 10.5.1 OS installed. I'm trying to enable developer options but tapping the serial number seven times does nothing. What should I do?

Comment: I hope you found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33079286/295004)

Comment: Of course. It is missing most of those buttons.